# What is the C datatype for BOOLEAN column in a Prepared Statement?

Tags: mysql, c, boolean, prepared-statement

One can create a column with a `BOOLEAN` datatype as detailed at [Create boolean column in MySQL with false as default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2221069/608639). For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  ID int NOT NULL,
  LastName varchar(255),
  FirstName varchar(255),
  Married boolean DEFAULT false
);
```

MySQL datatypes like `MYSQL_TYPE_INT` and `MYSQL_TYPE_STRING` are detailed in the manual at [23.8.9.1 C API Prepared Statement Type Codes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html). However, the manual does not discuss the `BOOLEAN` dataype or how to use it in a prepared statement. For example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

MYSQL_BIND bind[1];
...

bool val = false;
unsigned long len;
len = sizeof(???);

bind[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_<???>;
bind[0].buffer= (char*)&val;
bind[0].buffer_length = len;
bind[0].is_null= 0;
bind[0].length= &len;
```

What datatype do we use for a `BOOLEAN` type, and how do we calculate `MYSQL_BIND.buffer_length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, [`BOOLEAN` is a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

As such, you'd use the `MYSQL_TYPE_TINY` bind type.

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff. Do I need to convert the `bool val` to a `my_bool b = val`, and then use it like `bind[0].buffer= (char*)&b;`?

Comment: Yes, you should do that. The size of  `bool` is not guaranteed, so casting a `bool *` to `char *` may have unexpected effects.